# How to set HTML form input value, if element id, classname, other attributes are not known?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, automation, cefsharp

I could not find any solution for this. On the opened website in the browser I have `HTML` form with text input `textbox`. None of the attributes are not known. I am able to send programatically CLICK input on the `textbox` (by moving mouse to x,y and click on it) to make coursor active on it. But still I have no idea how to send with `JavaScript` inject a string input to the active textbox. I will be glad for any help. Whole project is in C#, with use of CefSharp and `EvaluateScriptAsync` method.

Comment: If you are able to find it to focus on it why can't you set value using same reference? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I am able programatically to move mouse to x,y and click on it. How to fill it up with string after click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the final I decided to use [InputSimulator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator) that pretends to write a letters in a place of clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

*one solution that i can think of is give the input element a classname and access it in javascript by classname and then set its text value*

eg:

Html

```
<input type="text" class="activeclass"/>

In javascript you can access this element by

var inputEl=document.getElementsByClassName('activeclass');
if(inputEl!=undefined)
inputEl.text="sampletext";
```

Comment: It is on the website, that I have no access to the source code. I want just to inject some code to do it. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: okay..you can find the active element on the document using document.activeElement.  So you can do something like below:                                                                                var y=document.activeElement;
y.value="hello";

Comment: Just tryed this and didnt work. I used `await wbPrzegladarka.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"
   var elem = document.activeElement;
   elem.value = '" + przetworzoneAudio + @"';
      ");`, where it is injected by code in `C#` and ` + przetworzoneAudio + ` is a various. I am worried here only about JS code. Maybe the `element` might be out of the reach of `activeElement`?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the coordinates of the element you can use [document.elementFromPoint(x, y);](https://javascript.info/coordinates#elementFromPoint) to target it

Comment: Because of some reason, it did not work. I used `await wbPrzegladarka.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"
   let elem = document.elementFromPoint(329, 287);
   elem.value = '" + przetworzoneAudio + @"';
      ");`, where it is injected by code in `C#` and ` + przetworzoneAudio + ` is a various. I am worried here only about JS code. Maybe the `element` might be out of the reach of `elementFromPoint`?